# MRTK V2 - How to access Receivers?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

At the beginning of my scene I set up all my OnClick- and OnFocus-Listeners (which you see in the code snippet at the end of this post).
As I'm using the given mrtk-prefab-buttons, which have the `Interactable` script on them, there is already under `Receivers` an `InteractableOnFocusReceiver`, you see in the screenshot below.

[image]

**My issue:**
 By adding an receiver (via the code below), everything works fine, but I get these message:
[image]
I guess this happens because there is already a `OnFocusReceiver` and I'm adding another one or I missing some extra data/component. So I tried to access somehow the `OnFocusReceiver` that already exists, but could not find a way to achieve that. Trying `comp.GetReceiver<InteractableOnFocusReceiver>();` is giving me `null` even though in the unity editor I see a OnFocusReceiver. **Does sb know how to access this receiver so I can just add to it another trigger-method?**

```
public static void ManageListenerForFocus(
    bool addReceiver, 
    Interactable comp, 
    Listener methodForFocusEnter, 
    Listener methodForFocusExit)
{
    var onFocusReceiver = comp.AddReceiver<InteractableOnFocusReceiver>();

    if (addReceiver)
    {
        onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOn.AddListener(() => methodForFocusEnter(comp));
        onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOff.AddListener(() => methodForFocusExit(comp));
    }
    else
    {
        onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOn.RemoveListener(() => methodForFocusEnter(comp));
        onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOff.RemoveListener(() => methodForFocusExit(comp));
    }
}

public static void ManageListenerForClicks(
    bool addListener,
    Interactable comp,
    UnityAction actionForOnClick)
{
    if (addListener)
        comp.OnClick.AddListener(actionForOnClick);
    else
        comp.OnClick.RemoveListener(actionForOnClick);
}
```

Comment: If you want to add another trigger method on this gameobject, you should click "+" in the OnFocusOn() list and select your function that will be called every time. Why would you want to add another one to the Interactable class under the same game object? Could you provide more information about your business requirements?

Comment: I just want to know how to add on runtime a method that get triggered by `OnFocus`. And because the prefab button already has a receiver on the `interactable`-component (which you see in the screenshot) I just want to add one method instead of adding a new receiver and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a method for OnFocusReceiver on runtime, you just need to add a listener to the existing receiver:

```
    var onFocusReceiver = gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>().GetReceiver<InteractableOnFocusReceiver>();
    onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOn.AddListener(() => Debug.Log("ONtest"));
    onFocusReceiver.OnFocusOff.AddListener(() => Debug.Log("OFFtest"));
```

Comment: And thats the problem I'm talking about. If I try this, `var onFocusReceiver` is null. It says that there is no receiver. But looking at my buttons in the editor(screenshot) I see that there is one

Comment: @Perazim Which prefab-button are you using? I tested this code with PressableButtonHoloLens2TextOnly_48x48 and it worked. Can you reproduce this issue in other new projects? What version of Unity and MRTK are you using?

Comment: I'm using MRTK v2.2, Unity 2019.3.3 and the Prefab for a collection of buttons I call it toolbar, you can see it on the [first picture here][1]. But I'm gonna retry it, maybe I did somewhere a mistake.                         
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/button

Comment: not by any stretch of imagination can I explain, why it works now. I did it multiple times before and had every time `null`. But now, after retrying, it works!
Also thanks for replying to my posts here on so!